# Recreating Power BI Formula in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, powerbi

```
Net Sales = CALCULATE(SUM('COMBINED'[Total]),'COMBINED'[Type]="Sales") + 
CALCULATE(SUM('COMBINED'[Total]),'COMBINED'[Type]="Sales Tax Expense") + 
CALCULATE(SUM('COMBINED'[Total]),'COMBINED'[Type]="Discounts")

Combined = Table Name
Total = Column with $ values
Type = Column with income / expense types.
```

So I have the above formula in Power BI that I'm trying to replicate as a calculated field in Tableau. How would I go about creating a field: "Net Sales" where the goal is to grab the SUM of Total where Type = 'Sales', 'Discounts', or 'Sales Tax Expense'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have already brought your data source to Tableau;

Create a calculated field called **Net Sales** and write below formula in it. When you drag the new field to your view as `SUM` (Which is the default aggregation, so normally you do not have to do anything for this), you will have the requested sum.

```
IF [Type] = 'Sales' or [Type] = 'Discounts' or  [Type] = 'Sales Tax Expense'

THEN [Total]

ELSE 0

END
```